# How to allow duplicate keys in a HashMap or TreeMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, key, treemap

I have been given an assignment where I need to use either a HashMap or TreeMap to hold a list of students and their grade. I assume that they key would be the name and the value would be the student's grade. I have been instructed to allow for students with the same name.

Because neither HashMap or TreeMap allow for duplicate keys I can't have the name be the key, correct?

Is there a simple way to allow for duplicate keys? How would a TreeMap sort duplicate keys?

I also need to be able to sort by name so I would prefer to use TreeMap.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looking for a different data structure, think about different keys you could use that *are* unique. This is a very common problem in software development, as many concepts in the real world aren't as unique as we'd like. Names (not just of people but also places and things) are a classic example.

While there are multiple potential solutions a common one is to assign each not-quite-unique thing a unique identifier and use *that* as your key. So your map might look like:

```
Map<Integer, Person>
```

This only offloads the problem, of course, since you now have to be able to look up a person's ID as well, assuming you only know their name. This can be done with a:

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>>
```

Where the keys are a name and the values are the set of IDs with that name. You'd then have to have some application-specific way to further disambiguate if necessary, such as asking the user to select one. This second `Map` can be a `TreeMap` if you need the names in alphabetical order, or you might choose to make `Person` implement `Comparable`.

The [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library also provides the very nice [`Multimap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) interface which makes data structures like `Map<K, Set<V>>` much easier to work with.